# PHP/HTML: activate users through admin page using radio button

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm creating an activate/deactivate based on the admin input.
The idea is to allow the admin to view all the accounts from accounts table and choose one from Selections (activate or deactivate ) using radios input. 
I really would appreciate it if you guys can help me out on this page, my project is almost done.
Thank you All for your suggestions, the I'm just trying to let the admin have the option to activate or deactivate from the user account, using this code.
The Code basically view all the informations of the accounts, and the admin just checkbox anyone she wants to activate and choose from the radios (activate/deactivate) and based on her input will set the value in the database to 0 which is deactivate and 1 to activate . 
thank you

```
<?php
session_start();
if( isset($_SESSION['username']) ){

//Connect to DB
//include_once("Project/CIEconn.php");
$mysqlCON= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","CIE") or die(mysqli_connect_error()); 
mysqli_select_db($mysqlCON,'CIE') or die ("no database");

if( isset($_POST['ActivateUsers']) ){
        if( empty($_POST['Id']) || $_POST['Id'] == 0 ){
            echo"<h4>  please choose someone to activate   </h4>";
        }else{

           $impid = implode("' , '" ,  $_POST['Id']);
$sqlDelete = "UPDATE  Accounts SET  Activated='$_POST[activate]'  WHERE Id IN ('" . $impid . "')";

$DeleteQuery = mysqli_query($mysqlCON,$sqlDelete) or die ("Error : ".mysqli_error($mysqlCON));

       }
}

$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM Accounts ";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqlCON,$sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error()); 

echo "<h1> Activate / Deactive User Account </h1>";

echo "<table border='1' width = 80% align=center >
<tr>
<th>Check </th>
<th>SSU ID</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>User Type </th>
<th>Activated</th>
<th>Activate/Deactive</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

echo "<tr>";
echo "<form action='ActivateD.php' method='post'>";
echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='Id[]' value='". $row['SSU'] ."' /> </td> "  ;
echo "<td align=center > " . $row['SSU'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align=center>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align=center>" . $row['First_Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align=center>" . $row['Last_Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align=center>" . $row['userType'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align=center>" . $row['Activated'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align=center>" .
"
 <input type='radio' name='activate'  value='1' > Activate
  <input type='radio' name='activate'  value='0'> Deactive
</form>"  
. "</td>";

echo "</tr> ";
}
echo "</table>";

echo " <br>
    <form action='ActivateD.php' method='post'>

                                <div align='center'>

<input type='submit' name='ActivateUsers' value='Activate/Deactive'>


                                </div>

    </form>";

mysqli_close($mysqlCON);

} 
  else{echo "must logout to see this page..!!";}

?>

<html>
<head><title> Activate / Deactive User Account </title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    background-color: #23438e;
}
table{
    background: white;

}

h1{
    color: #FF942B; 
    text-align: center;
    padding-top : 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include more information?  Things such as what the code is doing or not doing (and what you've tried) allow someone to provide better assistance.

Comment: thank you, I just added some informations to my post

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be several problems with your script:

1. You are wrapping a form around each of your radio inputs and checkboxes but a separate form around your submit button. In this setup, the form isn't going to send the right data when submitted.
2. Duplicating radio boxes with the same name on every row. Because you are only utilizing a single value for active/inactive, you should place one set of radio buttons at the bottom of your form.
3. Your SQL query escaping is incorrect:

Instead of 
`$sqlDelete = "UPDATE  Accounts SET  Activated='$_POST[activate]'  WHERE Id IN ('" . $impid . "')";`

You should use `$sql = "update Accounts set Activated='" . $_POST['activate'] . "' where Id in ('" . $impid . "')";`

4. Lack of error handling and input sanitization

Comment: I appreciate your help, it's my first project using php, and I'm learning as I go, I'll try to change the code as u said. and see

Comment: would u please explain more on #2  from ur recommendations ?

Comment: You have radio inputs with the same name 'activate' and different values. So no matter which radio the user selects, the value of $_POST['activate'] will 1 or 0 -- or rather will be if the radio was inside the form being submitted (with the submit button). If the user does not select any options that key won't be defined, so you should also check against it existing before running your update query. Since you are only allowing two options (1/0) it would make sense to only include your enable/disable radios once (top or bottom of form) instead of on every row.